# Python UN Comtrade API Error 429: Rate limit is exceeded

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to use UN Comtrade API to get some trade data but it is not working for me. First method I tried was using the comtradeapicall package and its public API.

Code I used is like this:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade comtradeapicall

import pandas
import requests
import comtradeapicall

comtradeapicall.previewFinalData(typeCode='C', freqCode='M', clCode='HS', period='202205', reporterCode='36', cmdCode='91', flowCode='M', partnerCode=None, partner2Code=None, customsCode=None, motCode=None, maxRecords=500,format_output='JSON', aggregateBy=None, breakdownMode='classic', countOnly=None, includeDesc=True)
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> Error in calling API: https://comtradeapi.un.org/public/v1/preview/C/M/HS?reportercode=36&flowCode=M&period=202205&cmdCode=91&maxRecords=500&format=JSON&breakdownMode=classic&includeDesc=True
> Error code: 429
> Error message: Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 1 seconds.

This is the exact same error message I get when I try to preview the data from the website without logging into my account. I don't know if this means that I need to somehow put my login info when I use API, but I'm not sure how. Also, I'm using the public API so I didn't think I need a subscription key.

The second method I've tried is using the URL itself:

```
import requests
url='https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2018&r=152&p=all&rg=all&cc=851712'
un_data=requests.get(url)
print(un_data.content)
```

But it also gives me this error message:

> b'{"validation":{"status":{"name":"Authorization","value":5001,"category":0,"description":"you do not have permissions to access this resource.","helpUrl":"For more reference visit [http://comtradedeveloper.un.org/"},"message":"Access](http://comtradedeveloper.un.org/%22%7D,%22message%22:%22Access) to legacy API is only allowed to premium users. Please visit https://comtradeplus.un.org to get free access.","count":{"value":0,"started":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","finished":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","durationSeconds":0.0},"datasetTimer":null},"dataset":[]}'

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me figure out what's causing this issue?